# How do I remove comma from strings for android?

Tags: android

What I have : text1,text2,text3
What I want : text1 text2 text3
replace comma with space?

Comment: string.replace(',',' ') or something like that..? did you try google?

Comment: For the next question add what you tried.

Comment: I tried with both replace and replaceAll. But didn't work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response in future, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

Comment: @EdGeorge weren't we used to be able to flag questions with the reason being something like your comment?

Comment: `-7 down votes proof that you haven't try anything before asking. even Google to.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
final String s = "text1,text2,text3".replace(",", " ");
```

> I tried with both replace and replaceAll. But didn't work

This is because both `replace()` and `replaceAll()` don't change the `String` object, they return you a new one. Strings [are immutable in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java).

Answer (score 4):

Try This Way:

```
String data = "text1,text2,text3";
String temp = data.replace(","," ");
```

Now You have all

Answer (score 1):

This what you should do

```
String str = "text1,text2,text3"
str = str.replace(","," ");
```